# Notepad++ search & replace regular expression

Tags: notepad++

i have to search and replace in notepad++ with placeholder. I tried a lot but i don't got it.

e.g. i want to search for:

`id="l_title"`

and replace it with:

`id="l_title_1"`

Of course the id name is different I want to search for `id="PLACEHOLDER"` and replace it with `id="PLACEHOLDER_1"`. I just want to add a `"_1"` to every id name.

Do you know regular expressions and can you help me?

i tried something like searching for id=".*" but this always selects the whole line until the last " character.
I also tried searching with id="[^"]++ but then i don't know what to type in replace because \1 doesn't work

SOLUTION:
it worked for me with:
search: (id="[^"]++)
replace: \1_1

Comment: For this use case you dont need regexp. Just a simple search and replace. Please add more details, why you think you need a "placeholder".

Comment: the id tile is different every time it appears in my code thats why i think i need a placeholder for the id name

Comment: Sorry, it was late and I didnot get it. You can use a RE like `(id="[^"]+)`. I think the second `+` in your RE is a bit strange. The plus expresses how often the previus part should be repeated. Although I  admit that your RE works well.

Comment: Instead of giving solution in the question, answer the question and mark it as accepted for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked for me with: search: (id="[^"]++) replace: \1_1